# This guy has a 101 rep with after only asking 2 questions and getting no up votes: Bug in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I really don't want to be a dick, but I ran across the following question: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/386327/how-to-learn-ubuntu-after-installing-it
from the following user:
https://askubuntu.com/users/172308/deepak
and I can't see why deepak would have the reputation he has... Is this a bug in the ask site itself?

Comment: [Reputation history is public](http://askubuntu.com/users/172308/deepak?tab=reputation)

Comment: A pretty good read about how reputation works from [help pages](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 13):

He has the association bonus from having ,more than 200 reputation on SO. This is as designed.

From the [help pages](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation)

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know.